# Display another div on specific option

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to show a div when specific option is selected.

```
<select id="post_category_select" onchange="if 
   ($('#post_category_select').val() == '3') {
      $('#post').show();
   } else {
     $('#post').hide();
   }">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<div id="post">
  Example
</div>
```

I'm saving those values to my database from add post page and i'm using same structure for edit page.

And my issue is, when i pull value from database on my edit page, i have to change option to 3 for see `div#post` even the option is 3.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what exactly you're trying to do. You want to set the `value` to `3` by default? Or do you want to display your `#post` field when `3` is selected?

Comment: @ObsidianAge I wanna display #post field when 3 is selected. But  if 3 is already selected after page load, i have to change option to 3 again for display #post field.

Comment: What errors do you get in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in the header, and you're good to go.  Then, make sure that your div you want to show has the ID of "writer".  It looks like it currently has an ID of "post"

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // First, grab the value of our select box as it is currently.
    var postSelect = $('#post_category_select').val();

    // If our current value is set to 3, we want to show the div.
    if(postSelect == '3') {
        $('#post').show();
    } else {
        // If it's not, hide it.
        $('#post').hide();
    }

    // Do the same thing when the input is changed.
    $('#post_category_select').change(function() {
        if($(this).val() == '3') {
            $('#post').show();
        } else {
            $('#post').hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an unobstrusive JavaScript handler for the change event on your select input and trigger the change event in the document ready function.

```
<select id="post_category_select">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3" selected="selected">3</option>
</select>
<div id="post">
  Example
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#post_category_select').change(function() {
            $('#post').toggle($(this).val() == '3');
        });
        $('#post_category_select').trigger('change');
    });
</script>
```